# C++ GetBinaryType Failing

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using `GetBinaryType` to check if an executable is 32 or 64bit. I am testing against a 64bit file and it keeps failing. I believe this is due to the way I am comparing the `DWORD` result?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C++:

```
DWORD dwBinaryType;
if (GetBinaryType(ChildFile(), &dwBinaryType) == 6)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"64bit Detected...", L"Debug: GetBinaryType", MB_OK); // DEBUG
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Probably 32bit...", L"Debug: GetBinaryType", MB_OK); // DEBUG
}
```

Any advice would be great thanks.

Comment: According to the MSDN page, you should be checking the value stored in `dwBinaryType`. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364819(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN for `GetBinaryType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364819(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Return value
>
> If the file is executable, the return value is nonzero. The function sets the variable pointed to by lpBinaryType to indicate the file's executable type.

Changing your above code to this should do the trick:

```
if (GetBinaryType(ChildFile(), &dwBinaryType)
    && dwBinaryType == SCS_64BIT_BINARY)
{
  // ...
}
```